# Configure Cloudflare to point to AWS Amplify

Tags: amazon-web-services, cloudflare, amazon-route53, aws-amplify

I use Cloudflare to generate SSL and AWS Amplify to host the project. I would like to configure Cloudflare to point to AWS Amplify project.

These are the current DNS records, which points to the current server.

[image]

This is the [project URL](https://tau.guide/) and the [URL](https://master.d178lhozvtcjvn.amplifyapp.com/) where is project deployed on AWS Amplify.

I tried to changed DNS records to point website to AWS Amplify project, but it doesn’t work.

[image]

Comment: stuck at the same step; pointed my subdomain to `https://d1xxxxxxxxxx.cloudfront.net/` in cloudflare, but when I try to open this url in the browser, I get: `<Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code>
<Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.</Message>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For your AWS Amplify Domain, you do not need to use Proxied, as it's already secure connection (https://master.DIGITS.amplify.com)

Before you add your subdomain entry in your DNS you also need to add an entry in your DNS to verify the ownership of the domain

[image]

After you have done the above step, you can get the DNS record name like this:

[image]

you need to add this entry in your DNS like this:

[image]

I hope this helps anyone looking for it, I found it hard myself as well.

EDIT: There have been some updates. You can check on this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html) from official docs. Also, you can make tweaks as explained by [Thananjaya S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7958988/thananjaya-s)  in the comment [below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65235069/12339664). Thanks

Comment: im going to try this out Monday morning with a new integration. first time doing this one with CloudFlare, hope it works! :)

Comment: @lopezdp sure, I hope it helps. do let me know here.

Comment: youre the man @afzal zubair! worked like a charm my friend!

Comment: better late than never 

Comment: @lopezdp thanks man, I'm glad that it worked for you.

Comment: Right now there is one more step involved in the setup to add an ANAME/ALIAS, but cloudflare doesnot support ANAME/ALIAS. so how to get this done in the current situation.

Answer (score 7):

Follow the steps as mentioned in this [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amplify/latest/userguide/to-add-a-custom-domain-managed-by-a-third-party-dns-provider.html), but remove from `Proxied` to `DNS only`. You can achieve it by clicking on the yellow cloud icon.

[image]

Comment: this tweak works for me.

Answer (score 0):

My journey started off with Amplify suggesting to add a CAA entry for [0 issue "amazontrust.com"], which I did and it did not solve anything.

I then read somewhere that the solution is to add all four of the suggested CAA entries:

```
0 issue "amazonaws.com"
0 issue "amazon.com"
0 issue "amazontrust.com"
0 issue "awstrust.com"
```

Unfortunately, this also did not work.

The issue got solved when I added a wildcard for all of the CAA certificates. In other words, this is the setup that worked for me:

```
0 issue "amazonaws.com"
0 issue "amazon.com"
0 issue "amazontrust.com"
0 issue "awstrust.com"
0 issuewild "amazonaws.com"
0 issuewild "amazon.com"
0 issuewild "amazontrust.com"
0 issuewild "awstrust.com"
```

Note: all entries are DNS only = not proxied...